# How to assign different actions for same UIButton?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui-button

while click on the button for the first time, the title of the button will get changed from "*Add to Cart*" to "*Go to Cart*". And from the next click the button will navigate to the next screen (cart page) [just like flipkart].

here is my piece of code:

```
    @IBAction func addToCartbtnTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        if let info = detailInfo {
            let cartData = CartStruct(cartItems: info, cartQuantity: 1)
            self.saveCart(data: cartData)
            showAlert()
            (sender as AnyObject).setTitle("Go to Cart", for: .normal)
            
            let cart = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CartViewController") as? CartViewController
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(cart!, animated: true)
        }
    }
```

I'm able to change the title of the button. But whenever I click on the button for nth number of time also, the product is getting added to the cart, screen is not navigating.

How to solve this issue?

Update..

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "btn")
    }



    @IBAction func addToCartbtnTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        if !Clicked {
            if let info = detailInfo {
                let cartData = CartStruct(cartItems: info, cartQuantity: 1)
                self.saveCart(data: cartData)
                showAlert()
                addingTOCart.setTitle("Go to Cart", for: .normal)
                UserDefaults.standard.set("Go to Cart", forKey: "btn")
                print("Clicked")
                Clicked = true
                return
            }
        }
        
        if Clicked {
            print("Perform Action")
            let cart = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CartViewController") as? CartViewController
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(cart!, animated: true)
        }
    }
```

This is how I am trying to store the "*Go to Cart*" state. But not working.. please suggest!

Comment: Just add an `isCartEmpty` boolean property and if true add to cart otherwise set it to false and present the cart view controller.

Comment: use Flag to maintain The Diffeciasion between Click Event

Comment: I don't know the syntax for "add an isCartEmpty boolean property"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this code to check cart is already added or not, If added change title according in your detail controller:

```
 override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
            if let info = detailInfo {
                let buttonTItle = (self.checkCartData(cartInfo: info) ? "Go to Cart"  : "Add to Cart")
                addToCartButton.setTitle(buttonTItle, for: .normal)
            }
        }
```

Next, Check before adding to cart. If already added, will navigate to cart page else add new cart item(changing button title too).

```
@IBAction func addToCartbtnTapped(_ sender: Any) {
            if let info = detailInfo {
                if checkCartData(cartInfo: info) {
                    let cart = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CartViewController") as? CartViewController
                    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(cart!, animated: true)
                } else {
                    let cartData = CartStruct(cartItems: info, cartQuantity: 1)
                    self.saveCart(data: cartData)
                    showAlert()
                    (sender as AnyObject).setTitle("Go to Cart", for: .normal)
                }
            }
        }
```

Check Cart data here:

```
        func checkCartData(cartInfo: jsonstruct) -> Bool {
            guard let cart = self.getCartData() else { return false }
            return (cart.contains(where: { $0.cartItems.name == cartInfo.name }) ? true : false )
        }
```

Get all Cart Data with this method:

```
        func getCartData() -> [CartStruct]? {
            let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
            var tempCart: [CartStruct]?
            if let cdata = defaults.data(forKey: "cartt") {
                tempCart = try! PropertyListDecoder().decode([CartStruct].self, from: cdata)
            }
            return tempCart
        }
```

Comment: why are you using UserDefaults .... while using PropertyList

Comment: "PropertyListDecoder" is a decoder, we can decode custom object from UserDefault.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply check on your button title for performing two different actions. Also you are showing alert and pushing View Controller at the same time which might be the reason for screen not navigating.

```
@IBAction func addToCartbtnTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if let info = detailInfo {
            switch sender.currentTitle! {
            case "Add to Cart":
                let cartData = CartStruct(cartItems: info, cartQuantity: 1)
                self.saveCart(data: cartData)
                showAlert()
                (sender as AnyObject).setTitle("Go to Cart", for: .normal)
            case "Go to Cart":
                let cartData = CartStruct(cartItems: info, cartQuantity: 1)
                self.saveCart(data: cartData)
                showAlert()
                (sender as AnyObject).setTitle("Go to Cart", for: .normal)
            default:
                print("Default Case")
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Never Check Strings or String case

Answer (score -1):

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

   @IBOutlet weak var btn: UIButton!
   var Clicked:Bool = false
   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
   }

   @IBAction func btnClick(_ sender: Any) {
       if !Clicked {
           btn.setTitle("Click", for: .normal)
           print("Clicked")
           Clicked = true
           return
       }
       
       if Clicked {
           print("Perform Action")
       }
       
   }

}
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. Can you please help me in one more issue?

Comment: Wheneven I am quitting the app/going. back to previous view controllers and then returning to the screen, "Add to Cart" title of the button is back again with adding to cart fascility, whereas the product has already been added to the cart. Then how to convert the title of the button as "Go to Cart" after once the product is added to the cart?

Comment: Use UserDefautls to store the Clicked Value